# Combining two lists into a list of dictionaries and all the values are the same

Tags: python, for-loop, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have two lists I want to combine :

```
old = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
new = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']
```

and I want to make a list of dict as shown below :

```
myList = [{'lama': 'aaa', 'baru': 'AAA'}, {'lama': 'bbb', 'baru': 'BBB'}, {'lama': 'ccc', 'baru': 'CCC'}]
```

what I tried was :

```
myList = []
myDict = {}

old = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
new = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']


for idx, value in enumerate(old):
    myDict['lama'] = old[idx]
    myDict['baru'] = new[idx]

    myList.append(myDict)
    
print(myList)
```

and the result is :

```
[{'lama': 'ccc', 'baru': 'CCC'}, {'lama': 'ccc', 'baru': 'CCC'}, {'lama': 'ccc', 'baru': 'CCC'}]
```

what should I do to get the result I want?
Thanks

Comment: I've suggested an edit to your question, and the primary reason why you're code doesn't work is because you are passing by reference (instead of by value) and so you append the reference over and over... One way to avoid this is to define the `myDict` variable inside your loop... Nabeel's code demonstrates part of this, and is why his works instead of yours (you don't necessarily need the zip function)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```py
myList = [{'lama': i, 'baru': j} for i, j in zip(old, new)]
```

Comment: Would you like to explain to the OP what this is doing and why it works? Maybe explain why their current code doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you @Beitian Ma, for the solution, but I still curious why `myDict` value always change in every loop and can I resolved this using pure loop (without zip) ?

Answer (score 2):

Your code has just one tiny problem where you initialize your dictionary. The repeated updates change the original dictionary in place so if you initialize it in the loop, it should work.

```
myList = []

old = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
new = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']


for idx, value in enumerate(old):
    myDict = {}
    myDict['lama'] = old[idx]
    myDict['baru'] = new[idx]
    print(myDict)
    myList.append(myDict)
    
print(myList)
```

You can also use `zip` to traverse lists with the same length simultaneously.

```py
old = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
new = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']

myList = []

for x,y in zip(old, new):
  myList.append({"lama": x, "baru":y})
```

Here's the output:

```
[{'lama': 'aaa', 'baru': 'AAA'}, {'lama': 'bbb', 'baru': 'BBB'}, {'lama': 'ccc', 'baru': 'CCC'}]
```

Comment: I was going to add an answer, but I see you have already left one... If you could update your answer to explain why their code isn't working, and what your code does to make it work I'll give you a +1... Otherwise this answer is just code that "works"...

Comment: @Nabeel, thanks for your solution